# php generating random numbers multiple of 10 with min and max

Tags: php, php-generators

I want to generate random numbers multiple of 10 with minimum and maximum conditions. Example 10, 40, 20, 100, 60. numbers between 10 and 100

Comment: Ok. What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Sound good.  If you encounter something in your code which prevents you from doing this and have a question to ask, let us know.

Comment: i am creating a file that will generate a random number before printing something so that the next following statement will change according to number that generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following segment will give your desire random number

```
mt_rand(ceil($min/10) , floor($max/10))*10;
```

**Please try something on your own before asking someone else to help you.**

Comment: If you're going to answer a question of such poor quality, you really should at the very least explain the code.

Comment: thnaks let me check